# How to parse an HAR file in java

Tags: java, performance-testing, har

I want to read the information from an `HAR` extension file using `Java`.
I am using Selenium Webdriver for capturing the timings, it generates a `.har` file.

I have seen we need to use some external libraries for this. I failed to find any links to download that library. Is anyone aware of what library I need and where I can find it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723400/get-response-data-using-harlib-in-java see this discussion may help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use these libraries in Java to read HAR file:

1. https://github.com/sdstoehr/har-reader
2. https://sites.google.com/site/frogthinkerorg/projects/harlib (introduction to the library)
3. http://sourceforge.net/projects/benchlab/files/HarLib/